# Hook up for Dayton AC motor with direction control

Tags: motor, connect

I have a Dayton single phase motor 1/2 HP and I need to control it's direction with two push button switches. Push and hold button1 for to turn on in CW direction, release and the motor stops. Push and hold button2 to turn on motor and run in the CCW direction, release and the motor stops. [image]

Can someone give me a schematic or any insight on doing this and where to connect the cap?

Answer (score 0):

If the motor has 2 identical windings, then:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjLVNI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Just make sure you NEVER press both push-button switches at the same time.

If the motor has a main winding and a auxiliary winding, then it's more complicated.

[image: schematic]

If a 3PST push button switch is hard to find, then you can use SPST switches driving relays.

To ensure that at no time both push-button switches are pressed, it s best to use a center-off momentary (On)-Off-(On) switch.